# SQL Select conditioned with input variable

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I have to execute SQL Server query in C# in a method. The scenario is:

The method is accepting a variable that is `string category`. If the value of `category = "Heterogeneous"` then I have to select as:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = con.CreateCommand();
if (simCategory == "Heterogeneous")
{
   myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityHeterogeneous FROM Graph  
   WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
}
else if (simCategory == "Low")
{
   myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityLow FROM Graph  
   WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
}
else if (simCategory == "Medium")
{
   myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityMedium FROM Graph  
   WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
}
else if (simCategory == "High")
{
   myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityHigh FROM Graph  
   WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
}

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceID", sID);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destinationID", dID);

using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      inNeighborActivationProbability = Convert.ToDouble(myReader["Probability"]);
   }
   myReader.Close();
}
```

Now, is this ture?

Comment: where is your `commandText` sentence? Just change it depending on the category parameter. I cant see any problem there.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza can't we put `Select @Probability ...` means a variable type after `SELECT`? As you suggesting to change `commandText`, then every time we need to change the query, but the question is about to put all this in a single query?

Comment: Nope. You cant change the fieldname using parameters. You need change your commandText based on the category, then add the parameters and execute the command. But be carefull because you can get sql injection if use one external string to build your query. Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I have updated query in the question. Could you have a look, is this fine now?

Comment: Look ok to me. And not sql injection possibility. Now go and test it ;)

Comment: You could simplify using a [**SWITCH**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) keyword. Also you have to validate you category have one of those 4 options otherwise you end with one empty commandText

Comment: It's all fine :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sure you can change the field depending on a parameter: simply use a `CASE @parameter WHEN 'Heterogeneous' THEN ProbabilityHeterogeneous WHEN 'Low' THEN ProbabilityLow  etc` construction. I'm not saying it's the best solution, but it would work perfectly and be SqlInjection-proof. It largely depends if you want to do the logic in c# (= on the client machine) or in SQL (= on the db machine). PS: It does require that all the fields return the same datatype, but going by the example I'm assuming that's a safe guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything (really) wrong with your code. The reason you probably think there is, is because you seem to be repeating a lot of code and that doesn't feel 'right' or 'efficient'. 
If you want to keep the decision about what field to use inside your c# code, then you can do things a bit more efficient like this:

```
        string fieldName;
        switch (simCategory)
        {
            case "Heterogeneous":
                fieldName = "ProbabilityHeterogeneous";
                break;

            case "Low":
                fieldName = "ProbabilityLow";
                break;

            case "Medium":
                fieldName = "ProbabilityMedium";
                break;

            case "High":
                fieldName = "ProbabilityHigh";
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(simCategory), "Unsupported Simulation Category requested.");
        }

        SqlCommand myCommand = con.CreateCommand();
        myCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT {0} as Probability FROM Graph WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID", fieldName);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceID", sID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destinationID", dID);

        using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
             etc...
```

This should be easier to read and maintain in case you ever need to add fields.

If for some reason you rather want to do the decision making in SQL (e.g. when you put the logic in a stored procedure, that way you can extend the db-model and functionality without having to upgrade each and every client-machine) you could build SQL code that looks like this:

```
SELECT (CASE @parameter WHEN 'Heterogeneous' THEN ProbabilityHeterogeneous
                        WHEN 'Low'           THEN ProbabilityLow
                        WHEN 'Medium'        THEN ProbabilityMedium
                        WHEN 'High'          THEN ProbabilityHigh
                                             ELSE NULL END) as Probability 
    FROM Graph 
    WHERE SourceID = @sourceID 
    AND DestinationID = @destinationID
```

Mind that in this case a 'wrong' parameter value will not result in an error but simply will return NULL as value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Switch` to  be more clear. Also you need use an alias on the `Probabilty`. So you can call it at the end no matter which one user choose: `myReader["Probability"]`

Finally try to include a default option just in case.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = con.CreateCommand();

switch (simCategory)
{
    case "Heterogeneous":
       myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityHeterogeneous as Probability FROM Graph  
                 WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
       break;

    case  "Low":
       myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityLow  as Probability FROM Graph  
                 WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
       break;

    case  "Medium":
       myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityMedium  as Probability FROM Graph  
                 WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
       break;

    case "High": 
       myCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT ProbabilityHigh as Probability FROM Graph  
                 WHERE SourceID = @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID";
       break;

    default:
          Console.WriteLine("Default case Rise ERROR?");
          break;
}

myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceID", sID);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destinationID", dID);

using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      inNeighborActivationProbability = Convert.ToDouble(myReader["Probability"]);
   }
   myReader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your column names are like 'Probability*' and ends by the simCategory, so I suggest the below code to be more clear

note: also you need to handle if the simCategory is null or empty.

```
string sql = "";
switch (simCategory)
{
 case "Heterogeneous":
 case  "Low":
 case  "Medium":
 case "High":        
     sql=simCategory;
     break;
 default:
       // handle error
     break;
}

SqlCommand myCommand = con.CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = string.Format(@"SELECT Probability{0}  as Probability FROM Graph WHERE SourceID =
                    @sourceID AND DestinationID = @destinationID", sql); 
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sourceID", sID);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destinationID", dID);

using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
 while (myReader.Read())
  {
   inNeighborActivationProbability = Convert.ToDouble(myReader["Probability"]);
  }
  myReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Just be aware that create vulnerability to sql injection attacks.